# Why is my location that I get with geoLocation.getCurrentPosition() not correct? (Leaflet)

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, location

The location that I get with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is not where my current location is. Everything other is working, but the `getPosition()` function creates a Marker, which is not at the location where I am.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Open-Source Map with Javascript</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Phil">

    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw; top:0; position: absolute; left: 0; z-index: 10" id="mapid"></div>

    <div id="div_alert" style="
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); position:absolute;
     display: none; text-align: center; vertical-align: center; z-index: 100;
      height: 75px; width: 350px;line-height: 75px; background: white; border-radius: 10px;
       top: 43%; left: 41%; color: gray;"></div>

    <script>

        /*
        *
        *   Sollte keine Standortabfrage kommen wir diese blockiert.
        *   Bitte die Datei lokal über den Browser öffnen (file::///...)
        *
        * */

        let div_alert = document.getElementById("div_alert");
        let mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([52.4315096,7.7865093,18.12]);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(mymap);

        L.marker([52.4315096,7.7865093,18.12]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("<b>Location</b><br />Test").openPopup();

        mymap.invalidateSize();

        function getPosition() {
            if(navigator.geolocation)
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            try{
                div_alert.innerHTML = "Standort wurde gefunden.";
                div_alert.style.display = "block";
                setTimeout(function() {
                    mymap.setView([position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude, position.coords.accuracy]);
                    div_alert.style.display = "none";
                    L.marker([position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude, position.coords.accuracy])
                        .addTo(mymap).bindPopup("<b>Location</b><br />Aktuelle Position").openPopup();
                }, 3000);
            } catch (Expression){
                alert("Fehler aufgetreten. [" + Expression + "]");
                console.log(Expression);
            }
        }
        getPosition();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please write in english

Comment: You probably use the Internet on a cable not from the telephone provider. And it's normal that the geolocation is wrong. You have the coordinates of your internet operator's server that can be in different places and also change every time you connect to the operator - dynamic IP.
It is best to test by setting the coordinates in the browser rigidly or on the phone.

Comment: Sigh. There is missing information: expected result vs actual result.

Comment: The expected result is the actual location coords. The actual result are location coords in a country beside (like 10km away).